# Using an array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, variables

This seems really simple but I can't find a way to make this work in a program I'm making. I have two classes, and in one of them, I've created an array, that I want to access in another class.

This is the main class...

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[] pixelValues;
    pixelValues = [99]; 
    }
}
```

Of course, I'm omitting a lot, but this is the code I'm having trouble with. There's a second class that goes a little like this...

```
public class pixelAssign {
    public pixelAssign(posX, posY) {
         main.pixelValues[ {some number} ] = {some value};
    }
}
```

My problem is that I'm having trouble accessing the pixelValues array that I created in my main class from a function I made in the second bit of code. I've been getting an error in the second bit of code that say (1), says that variable can't be found, and (2), I'm missing an identifier (?). The code in this is a bit unfinished, but the function in the second bit would be called from the main class later.

Any help would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting [Paul's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152861/paul-macguiheen) and [SANM2009's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5724824/sanm2009) answers together:

You should:

```
public class main {
    static int[] pixelValues;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pixelValues = [99];
    }
}

public class pixelAssign {
    public pixelAssign(posX, posY) {
         main.pixelValues[0] = 98;
    }
}
```

That should work IF and only IF classes main and pixelAssign are in the same package! If not, pixelValues would not be visible.

If you want to hold with Java Good Practices:

1. First letter of classes are always Uppercase, so Main and PixelAssign
2. Often is a good practice to instante classes and use the objects. Otherwise you have to use `static`.
3. Set pixelValues as `private` or `protected` and create method:

   ```
   public class Main {
       private int[] pixelValues;

       public Main() {
           pixelValues = [99];
       }

       public void setPixelValue(int position, int value) {
           pixelValues[position] = value;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            Main main = new Main();
            new PixelAssign(main);
       }
   }

   public class PixelAssign {
       public PixelAssign(Main main, posX, posY) {
           main.setPixelValue(0, 98);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your function so that it accepts the array as a parameter. you can then send the array to classB from ClassA.

There seems to be another issue here.

pixelValues is meant to be an array of Boolean or some numbers (int)?

```
boolean[] pixelValues;
pixelValues = [99];
```

As for the function:

```
public pixelAssign(myArray, posX, posY) {
}
```

So when calling the function, use

```
pixelAssign(pixelValues, posX, posY)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit how I'd do that? I'm pretty sure I know what you're saying, though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have changed the code to make it more concise but it looks like you are simply declaring the array in the wrong scope. Could you change it to this;

```
public class main {
    boolean[] pixelValues;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pixelValues = [99]; 
    }
}
```